# Java Optional.ofNullable(Object[] objects) with streams and boolean result

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to implement a utility method like this

```
boolean allNotNull( LocalDate... objects )
```

so that it returned `true` only for the case when there are elements (`objects` vararg is not `null`) and there are no `null` elements inside it. Also I want to implement it in functional style using Streams and Optionals and not involving any if statements.

The solution seemed to be obvious:

```
private static boolean allNotNull( LocalDate... objects )
{

    boolean allNotNull = Optional.ofNullable( objects )
                                 .stream()
                                 .flatMap( Arrays::stream )
                                 .noneMatch( Objects::isNull );
    return allNotNull;
}
```

But it always returns `true` if `objects` vararg is `null`. The reason must be that `Optional.stream()` returns `Stream.empty()` for this case which always returns `true` despite the predicate:

```
    Assert.assertTrue( Stream.empty().noneMatch( o -> true ));   //always true
    Assert.assertTrue( Stream.empty().noneMatch( o -> false ));  //also always true
```

I feel very stupid, but my question would be: is there a way to implement a utility method like this using `Optional.ofNullable()` for input varargs (arrays/colections) using only streams and optionals and avoiding ifs?

Below is my main method with some tests:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Assert.assertFalse( allNotNull( null ) );

    Assert.assertFalse( allNotNull( LocalDate.now(), null, LocalDate.MIN ) );

    Assert.assertTrue( allNotNull( LocalDate.MIN ) );
    Assert.assertTrue( allNotNull( LocalDate.MIN, LocalDate.EPOCH, LocalDate.EPOCH ) );

    Assert.assertFalse( allNotNull() );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe use `OrElse` to submit an array containing only `null` to the rest of your process when your `Optional` is not present (is `null`)

Comment: Just put an `if (Objects.isNull(objects)) { return false; }` at the start of the method.

Comment: @Turing85 yes, that would work, but I just want to make sure that I'm not missing an opportunity with that Optional.ofNullable()

Comment: @julien.giband yes, I expect it might work, but I cannot figure out where to put it. Probably somewhere before calling stream(), but how do I call stream() after unseccessful orElse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not try the code, but it should work like this (if you insist using Optionals):

```
boolean allNotNull( LocalDate... objects ){
   return Optional.ofNullable(objects)
                  .map(Arrays::stream)
                  .map(s -> s.noneMatch(Objects::isNull))
                  .orElse(false);
}
```

Without Optionals you could write it as

```
boolean allNotNull( LocalDate... objects ){
   return objects != null && Arrays.stream(objects).noneMatch(Objects::isNull);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working, thanks a lot, didn't think of nested stream! Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...or to ensure the method does what it speaks of you can `allMatch(Objects::nonNull)`